# jquery expanding and resizing problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this jquery to try and control how wide and high a div opens depending on the screen resolution this is the code im using but it doesn't seem to be having any effect apart from cropping my image. I say it doesnt seem to work becuase it leaves a big space and when I look at firebug it tells me the box has expanded to the 600px x 488px when im viewing in the lower resolution.

Im not sure if the images are pushing the div out the that size because the pictures are exactly 600px x 488px but I need them to be the same file just smaller for dynamic PHP gallery updating in the future, how can I fix this code and how can I easily resize the images depending on the resolution?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ((screen.width>=1440) && (screen.height>=764)) {


$("#slideshow_box")
    .animate({"height": "600px"}, 500)
    .animate({"width": "488px"}, 500);

}
else  {

$("#slideshow_box")
    .animate({"height": "400px"}, 500)
    .animate({"width": "288px"}, 500);


}
});
```

Comment: @Blender [screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen) is a native object in the DOMWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/PZGbw/)

As you can se [HERE](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml) even if you resize your screen the calculated width is actually = your brand new ;) screen - size!
To get the actual 'screen' (window!) size in your browser you can use

`$(window).width();` and `$(window).height();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var winW = $(window).width();
    var winH = $(window).height();
    alert("Window width is: "+winW+"px, window height is: "+winH+'px');
    if ((winW>=1440) && (winH>=764)) {
        $("#slideshow_box")
            .animate({"height": "600px"}, 500)
            .animate({"width": "488px"}, 500);
    } else {
        $("#slideshow_box")
            .animate({"height": "400px"}, 500)
            .animate({"width": "288px"}, 500);   
    }
});
```

---

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/PZGbw/2/)** you can see it in action, just resize the frame.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#size').html(
        ' Window width: '+$(window).width()+
        '<br> Window height: '+$(window).height()
    );
});
```

Comment: Hi mate thanks for the help this seems to have worked. I have another div inside the #slideshow_box div called #slideshow which contains the images for the slider. Your code is stopping the gap and resizing the box fine but the images inside the #slideshow div arnt resizing, is there a way of getting them to?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, can't figure out your problem...seems to work for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/EtEzN/2/

For sure, your snippet resizes DIV layer only, so you have to resize containing images too!

**EDIT:** Fiddle is updated, so script regards browsers document height instead of screen height (remember: screen resolution <> browser resolution <> document resolution)

Comment: Really, it doesnt work for me in Js Fiddle. It still only exicutes the 600 x 400px animation even when my browser has been resized smaller then that function call i.e smaller then 1440 x 764

Comment: Ha! browser size != screen size

Answer (score 0):

The images are indeed pushing out your `div`. If you want to change image size, then you can't just adjust the size of the containing `div`, you have to change the size of the `img` itself.

I'm assuming that the image is intended to be the same size as the `div` that contains it. Thus, your code should only require a slight modification:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ((screen.width>=1440) && (screen.height>=764)) {

// Since the image is already the same size as the div,
// don't change the image
$("#slideshow_box")
    .animate({"height": "600px"}, 500)
    .animate({"width": "488px"}, 500);
}
else  {

// Resize the image along with the div
$("#slideshow_box, #slideshow_box img")
    .animate({"height": "400px"}, 500)
    .animate({"width": "288px"}, 500);
}
});
```

Also, the `screen` properties signify the resolution of the client's display screen, not the actual size of the browser window. Since you're using jQuery, you can use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`, or if you're ever using plain JS, the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` properties (for Firefox), or `document.body.clientWidth` for IE, although browser compatibility is annoying for this, so I'd probably stick with jQuery or another library.